# SQL updates to table using WINDOW-like function in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-update, amazon-redshift, window-functions

I have a report that summarizes sales deals by rep, account, deal number, and a flag if they have been contacted by HQ to see if they need additional help. As I extract the data, I can see that some sales reps have multiple deals in progress at the same account.

Here's a sample of the report.  In this sample, Sales rep A has been contacted but Sales rep B has never been contacted.  We want to fill in the Sales rep A contacted fields while leaving Sales rep B as

```
opportunity owner | Account   | contacted   | deal no.
--------------------------------------------------------
Sales rep A       | account 1 | Sales rep A | 1
Sales rep A       | account 2 | <null>      | 2
Sales rep A       | account 1 | <null>      | 3
Sales rep B       | account a | <null>      | 1
Sales rep B       | account b | <null>      | 2
...
```

I want to update the contacted column with either 'Sales rep A' (or 'YES')
so that it looks like this:

```
opportunity owner | Account   | contacted   | deal no.
--------------------------------------------------------
Sales rep A       | account 1 | Yes         | 1
Sales rep A       | account 2 | Yes         | 2
Sales rep A       | account 1 | Yes         | 3
Sales rep B       | account a | <null>      | 1
Sales rep B       | account b | <null>      | 2
...
```

This looks like a case for a window function to me, but maybe a self-join would be better.  I tried to work out what the select function would look like

```
SELECT "opportunity owner", "contacted", "Account", "deal no."
DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION by 
--"opportunity owner"
 (SELECT "opportunity owner" FROM "test_weekly_top_deal_report" WHERE "worked with this rep before?"  LIKE 'Sales rep A')) AS "rank"

FROM "test_weekly_top_deal_report"
WHERE "opportunity owner"  LIKE 'Sales rep A'
```

Which gives me:

```
opportunity owner | Account   | contacted   | deal no.
--------------------------------------------------------
Sales rep A       | account 1 | Sales rep A | 1
Sales rep A       | account 2 | <null>      | 2
Sales rep A       | account 1 | <null>      | 3
```

But when I modified it to run over ***all*** the reps, I used this:

```
SELECT "opportunity owner", "worked with this rep before?", "account name",
DENSE_RANK () OVER (PARTITION by 
--"opportunity owner"
 (SELECT "opportunity owner" FROM "test_weekly_top_deal_report" WHERE "worked with this rep before?"  NOT LIKE 'NO')) AS "rank"

FROM "test_weekly_top_deal_report"
```

With just the small change in the WHERE clause now reading "NOT LIKE 'NO' ".  That just gave me an error:

```
The database reported a syntax error: [Amazon](500310) Invalid operation: 
Invalid Query: Details: ----------------------------------------------- error: 
Invalid Query: code: 8001 context: single-row subquery returns more than one row query: 2151115 location: 0.cpp:8
```

Suggestions? How do I make this iterate over all the reps and thus fill in the column "contacted"?

Answer (score 0):

```
select ("opportunity owner" from "test_weekly_top_deal_report"
    where "contacted" is "opportunity owner") as X;
select case
   when ("opportunity owner" in (X)) and ("contacted" is null or "contacted" is "opportunity owner")
   then 'Yes'
   else 'No' as contacted
from "test_weekly_top_deal_report"
```

Comment: Thanks, @ketcham for the response.  I wasn't clear in the request.  I only want to update those reps who have been contacted.  So the logic is a little more complicated - if any one row per rep is NOT null, then set all contacted rows to be the name of the rep.  Repeat for all reps.  I updated the sample table to be clearer.

Comment: Ah I see- just edited. I am unfortunately not able to test that at the moment but that should be along the lines of what you need